# Changing my query into a stored procedure?

Tags: stored-procedures

Here is the query (MS SQL):

```
use DB_432799_satv

select [DB_432799_satv].[dbo].ac_Orders.OrderNumber, OrderDate, PaymentDate, 
    CompletedDate, ShipDate,DateTimeFinishedPicking,DateTimeShipped, 
    ShipMethodName, PaymentMethodName
from [DB_432799_satv].[dbo].ac_Orders
Inner join [DB_432799_satv].[dbo].ac_Payments on 
    [DB_432799_satv].[dbo].ac_Orders.OrderId  = 
    [DB_432799_satv].[dbo].ac_Payments.OrderId
Inner join [DB_432799_satv].[dbo].ac_OrderShipments on  
    [DB_432799_satv].[dbo].ac_Orders.OrderId = 
    [DB_432799_satv].[dbo].ac_OrderShipments.OrderId
Inner join [DB_432799_satv].[dbo].[ac_Transactions] on 
    [DB_432799_satv].[dbo].ac_Payments.paymentid = 
    [DB_432799_satv].[dbo].ac_Transactions.paymentid
Inner join [SuperATV].[dbo].[tblPartsBoxHeader] on 
    [DB_432799_satv].[dbo].[ac_transactions].[ProviderTransactionId] = 
    [SuperATV].[dbo].[tblPartsBoxHeader].[ordernumber]
```

How would I change this into a stored procedure?

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: Perhaps you mean a "view"? It doesn't "do" (read: "process") anything...

Comment: @njk syntax looks like MSSQL.

Comment: ouch, my eyes hurt after looking at that! you can remove those unnecessary `[` braces `]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect what you want is what a "view" will give you. Specifically, to store that query in the database and select from it like:

```
SELECT * FOM myLongQueryView WHERE OrderNumber = 1234;
```

I don't develop MSSQL, but a quick search turned up [this doc page on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx). I suppose it would go something like this:

```
CREATE VIEW [DB_432799_satv].myLongQueryView
AS 
select [DB_432799_satv].[dbo].ac_Orders.OrderNumber, OrderDate, PaymentDate, 
    CompletedDate, ShipDate,DateTimeFinishedPicking,DateTimeShipped, 
    ShipMethodName, PaymentMethodName
from [DB_432799_satv].[dbo].ac_Orders
...
```

Simply prepend your query with `CREATE VIEW [DB_432799_satv].myLongQueryView AS`, and use the docs page to decide if any options are desired.

It's important to note that *query* is stored, not it's current results. So it stays up to date with your data. It is joinable, aggregatable, etc...